# Iterating multiple variables within For Loop in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, variables, printing

How would I be able to create a for loop where it will take in 2 parameters `num` and  `names` and iterates them both in the for loop. How would I be able to do that?

```
num<-c(1,2,3)
names<-c('one','two','three')
for (n in num, n2 in names) {
    print("%s : %i",n2,n)
}
```

Comment: `for (i in seq_along(num)) { n <- nums[i]; n2 <- names[i]; ... }`. FYI, it's likely not a good idea to use `names` as a variable, it's a fairly common base R function.

Comment: I tried your approach with code `(i in seq_along(num)) { print("Calculating for %s \n" , names[i] ) }` but it does not work. Would you know how I can resolve this?

Comment: See my answer. For reference, "does not work" does not work. When you say it like that with no error/warning message and no clear indication what's going on, you are requiring that we run your code just to be able to see the error that you have. Many times with many types of questions, we provide suggests without running the code (often not being able to run it, i.e., on our phones). Had you said *"does not work, it errors with `invalid printing digits -2147483648`"*, there's a strong chance somebody could have fixed it in a comment without needing to run your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can't iterate over two vectors like that, you need to index over one vector that indexes among them both, and then subset your vectors manually.
2. Your `print` is broken, attempting to pass `digits=n2` (and `quote=n`), which obviously won't work. I suspect you need `sprintf`.

```r
num<-c(1,2,3)
names<-c('one','two','three')
for (i in seq_along(num)) {
    n <- num[i]
    n2 <- names[i]
    print(sprintf("%s : %i",n2,n))
}
# [1] "one : 1"
# [1] "two : 2"
# [1] "three : 3"
```

BTW: this presumes that all such vectors are the same length.